# How to show image and video files from the Storage folder?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm storing some files (images, video files, word docs etc.) in storage/app/public folder. Within the public folder, I have 3 folders images, resumes, videos.

Everything works on localhost, but after deploying the site to GoDaddy, when a Candidate is viewing his own profile where he can Edit it of course, none of the files from within the storage folder are displaying anymore and I'm getting 403 errors in the console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

I properly linked the storage folder in my app, so I'm not sure how to fix this.
I'm using Laravel and Vue js for the front end.

Here is my vue file. At the top is where I'm displaying the Profile on the page and below that is my EditModal Form.

ProfileIndex.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

                <div v-if="Object.keys(profiles).length > 0">
                    <b-row>
                        <b-col>
                            <h3 class="card-title">My Profile</h3>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col class="text-right" v-for="(profile, index) in profiles" :key="index">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-right" v-on:click="editProfile(profile)"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Edit</button>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>

                    <b-row v-for="(profile, index) in profiles" :key="index">
                        <b-col md="3" sm="6" class="mb-3"><strong>Job Title</strong><br>
                            {{profile.job_title}}
                        </b-col>

                        <template v-for="(photo, index) in photos" v-if="photo.file === 'null'">
                            <b-col md="3" sm="6" class="mb-3"><strong>Photo</strong><br>
                                <img src="/images/placeholder-square.jpg" alt="" class="w-100px" />
                            </b-col>
                        </template>

                        <template v-else>
                            <b-col md="3" sm="6" v-for="(photo, index) in photos" :key="index" class="mb-3"><strong>Photo</strong><br>
                                <img :src="`${$store.state.serverPath}/storage/images/${photo.file}`" alt="" class="w-100px" />
                            </b-col>
                        </template>

                        <b-col md="3" sm="6" class="mb-3"><strong>Date of Birth</strong><br>
                            {{profile.date_of_birth}}
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col md="3" sm="6" class="mb-3"><strong>Employment Type</strong><br>
                            {{profile.employment_type}}
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>

                    <b-row class="mt-3">
                        <b-col md="4" sm="6" v-for="(video, index) in video_one" :key="index" class="mb-3"><strong>Video One</strong><br>
                            <b-embed
                                type="video"
                                aspect="16by9"
                                :src="`${$store.state.serverPath}/storage/videos/${video.file}`"
                                allowfullscreen
                                controls
                            ></b-embed>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col md="4" sm="6" v-for="(video, index) in video_two" :key="index" class="mb-3"><strong>Video Two</strong><br>
                            <b-embed
                                type="video"
                                aspect="16by9"
                                :src="`${$store.state.serverPath}/storage/videos/${video.file}`"
                                allowfullscreen
                                controls
                            ></b-embed>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col md="4" sm="6" v-for="(video, index) in video_three" :key="index" class="mb-3"><strong>Video Three</strong><br>
                            <b-embed
                                type="video"
                                aspect="16by9"
                                :src="`${$store.state.serverPath}/storage/videos/${video.file}`"
                                allowfullscreen
                                controls
                            ></b-embed>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>

                    <b-row class="mt-3">
                        <b-col v-for="(resume, index) in resumes" :key="index" class="mb-3"><strong>Resume</strong><br>
                            {{resume.file}}
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>

                    <b-row class="mt-3">
                        <b-col class="mb-3" v-for="(profile, index) in profiles" :key="index"><strong>Experience</strong><br>
                            {{profile.experience}}
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>

                    <b-row class="mt-3">
                        <b-col class="mb-3" v-for="(profile, index) in profiles" :key="index"><strong>Skills</strong><br>
                            {{profile.skills}}
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                    Your profile doesn't exist yet. Please <router-link to="/candidate/profile/create">create profile.</router-link>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <b-modal ref="editProfileModal" id="modal-1" title="Update Profile" hide-footer>
            <form v-on:submit.prevent="updateProfile">

                <b-row>
                    <b-col lg="6" md="6" sm="12">
                        <b-form-group label="Job Title" label-for="job_title">
                            <b-form-input
                                v-model="editProfileData.job_title"
                                id="job_title"
                                placeholder="Enter job title"
                            ></b-form-input>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.job_title">{{ errors.job_title[0] }}</div>
                        </b-form-group>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col lg="6" md="6" sm="12">
                        <span class="mt-4 d-block text-danger"><strong>Important:</strong> this is how employers will find you.</span>
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>

                <b-form-group label="Upload Profile Photo (optional)" label-for="photo_id">
                    <div v-if="editProfileFiles.photo_id.name">
                        <img src="" ref="newProfilePhotoDisplay" class="w-130" />
                    </div>
                    <b-form-file
                        v-model="editProfileFiles.photo_id"
                        id="photo_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"
                        ref="newProfilePhoto"
                    ></b-form-file>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group
                    label="Date of Birth"
                    label-for="date-of-birth"
                >
                    <b-form-input
                        type="date"
                        v-model="editProfileData.date_of_birth"
                        id="date-of-birth"
                    >
                    </b-form-input>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.date_of_birth">{{ errors.date_of_birth[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>
                <b-form-group
                    label="Employemnt Type"
                    label-for="employment-type"
                >
                    <b-form-radio-group
                        id="employment-type"
                        v-model="editProfileData.employment_type"
                        :options="options"
                        name="employment-type"
                    >
                    </b-form-radio-group>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.employment_type">{{ errors.employment_type[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group label="Resume" label-for="resume_id">
                    <b-form-file
                        v-model="editProfileFiles.resume_id"
                        id="resume_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        @change="editAttachResume"
                        accept=".doc,.docx"
                    ></b-form-file>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.resume_id">{{ errors.resume_id[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>

                <h4 class="mb-3">Please attach a few short videos (30 seconds max) for a better chance of being noticed. (optional)</h4>

                <b-form-group label="1. Tell us a little about yourself: (attach video)" label-for="video_one_id">
                    <b-form-file
                        v-model="editProfileFiles.video_one_id"
                        id="video_one_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        @change="editAttachVideoOne"
                        accept=".mp4, .mpeg4"
                    ></b-form-file>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group label="2. Tell us about your past work experiences: (attach video)" label-for="video_two_id">
                    <b-form-file
                        v-model="editProfileFiles.video_two_id"
                        id="video_two_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        @change="editAttachVideoTwo"
                        accept=".mp4, .mpeg4"
                    ></b-form-file>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group label="3. What sets you apart?: (attach video)" label-for="video_three_id">
                    <b-form-file
                        v-model="editProfileFiles.video_three_id"
                        id="video_three_id"
                        placeholder="Choose a file..."
                        @change="editAttachVideoThree"
                        accept=".mp4, .mpeg4"
                    ></b-form-file>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group label="Experience" label-for="experience">
                    <b-form-textarea
                        id="experience"
                        v-model="editProfileData.experience"
                        placeholder="Tell us a little about your experience..."
                        :rows="10"
                        :max-rows="12"
                    >
                    </b-form-textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.experience">{{ errors.experience[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-form-group label="Skills" label-for="skills">
                    <b-form-textarea
                        id="skills"
                        v-model="editProfileData.skills"
                        placeholder="List your skills..."
                        :rows="4"
                        :max-rows="6"
                    >
                    </b-form-textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.skills">{{ errors.skills[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>

                <b-row>
                    <b-col class="text-left">
                        <b-button v-on:click="hideEditProfileModal()" variant="light">Cancel</b-button>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col class="text-right">
                        <b-button type="submit" variant="success" class="mr-2"
                        ><i class="mdi mdi-check-circle"></i> Update</b-button
                        >
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>
            </form>
        </b-modal>

    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import * as groupedService from '../../../services/grouped_data_service.js';
    import * as profileService from '../../../services/candidate_profile_service.js';

    export default {
        name: "candidateProfileIndex",

        data() {
            return {
                profiles: [],
                profile: [],
                video_one: [],
                video_two: [],
                video_three: [],
                resumes: [],
                photos: [],

                options: [
                    { text: "Full Time", value: "Full Time" },
                    { text: "Part Time", value: "Part Time" },
                ],

                profileData: {
                    job_title: '',
                    photo_id: '',
                    employment_type: "Full Time",
                    date_of_birth: "",
                    experience: "",
                    skills: "",
                    resume_id: '',
                    video_one_id: '',
                    video_two_id: '',
                    video_three_id: ''
                },

                editProfileFiles: {
                    photo_id: [],
                    resume_id: [],
                    video_one_id: [],
                    video_two_id: [],
                    video_three_id: []
                },

                editProfileData: {},

                errors: {}
            };
        },

        mounted() {
            this.loadGroupedData();
        },

        methods: {
            loadGroupedData: async function() {
                try {
                    const response = await groupedService.loadGroupedData();
                    this.resumes = response.data.resumes;
                    this.video_one = response.data.video_one;
                    this.video_two = response.data.video_two;
                    this.video_three = response.data.video_three;
                    this.photos = response.data.photos;
                    this.profiles = response.data.profiles;

                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
                }
            },

            hideEditProfileModal() {
                this.$refs.editProfileModal.hide();
            },

            showEditProfileModal() {
                this.$refs.editProfileModal.show();
            },

            editProfile(profile) {
                this.editProfileData = {...profile};
                this.showEditProfileModal();
            },

            editAttachImage() {
                this.editProfileFiles.photo_id = this.$refs.newProfilePhoto.files[0];
                console.log(this.editProfileFiles.photo_id);
                // let reader = new FileReader();
                // reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
                //     this.$refs.newCategoryImageDisplay.src = reader.result;
                // }.bind(this), false);
                //
                // reader.readAsDataURL(this.categoryData.image);
            },
            editAttachResume(evt) {
                const file = evt.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', function() {

                }.bind(this), false);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
            editAttachVideoOne(evt) {
                const file = evt.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();

                if (file['size'] < 10485760) {
                    reader.addEventListener('load', function() {

                    }.bind(this), false);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                    this.$toast.error('File exceeds 10 MB limit. Please try again.');
                }
            },
            editAttachVideoTwo(evt) {
                const file = evt.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();

                if (file['size'] < 10485760) {
                    reader.addEventListener('load', function() {

                    }.bind(this), false);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                    this.$toast.error('File exceeds 10 MB limit. Please try again.');
                }
            },
            editAttachVideoThree(evt) {
                const file = evt.target.files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();

                if (file['size'] < 10485760) {
                    reader.addEventListener('load', function() {

                    }.bind(this), false);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                    this.$toast.error('File exceeds 10 MB limit. Please try again.');
                }
            },
            updateProfile: async function() {
                try {
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('job_title', this.editProfileData.job_title);
                    formData.append('photo_id', this.editProfileFiles.photo_id);
                    formData.append('employment_type', this.editProfileData.employment_type);
                    formData.append('date_of_birth', this.editProfileData.date_of_birth);
                    formData.append('experience', this.editProfileData.experience);
                    formData.append('skills', this.editProfileData.skills);
                    formData.append('resume_id', this.editProfileFiles.resume_id);
                    formData.append('video_one_id', this.editProfileFiles.video_one_id);
                    formData.append('video_two_id', this.editProfileFiles.video_two_id);
                    formData.append('video_three_id', this.editProfileFiles.video_three_id);

                    const response = await profileService.updateProfile(this.editProfileData.id, formData);

                    Object.keys(this.profiles).map(profile => {
                        if (profile.id == response.data.id) {
                            for (let key in response.data) {
                                profile[key] = response.data[key];
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    this.loadGroupedData();
                    this.hideEditProfileModal();
                    this.$toast.success("Profile Updated Successfully!");
                } catch (error) {
                    this.$toast.error(error.response.data.message);
                }

            },

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: First thing to check: what's the value of `$store.state.serverPath` on your GoDaddy instance?

Comment: so that it simply my domain https://highrjobs.com/

Comment: Artisan storage link command will need to be ran on your godaddy server

Comment: Ok it's your domain, but does it include the protocol? In other words, is your image src attribute generating a proper absolute url? I would try and print out `${$store.state.serverPath}/storage/images/${photo.file}` and see what url you are actually putting there...

Comment: It includes the protocol, "https://"
Is this wrong?

Comment: Nope - not wrong: just wanted to make sure it was a full absolute path - which it appears it is, based on what you say. So the 403 error usually means "Forbidden", suggesting maybe the images on GoDaddy are in a folder that is not accessible. You said you properly linked the storage folder, so have you checked you don't have a file/folder permission issue?

Comment: Sorry, you were right. The sym link wasn't created properly on the server.